# shebang not working to run bash scripts in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shebang

I can't seem to get bash scripts to turn into executable files via shebang. My code looks like

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "hello"
```

where this is in a file called **test.sh**. I'm trying to get it to run with the command

```
./test.sh
```

in the command line but i just receive the error of **permission denied**. When i change it to

```
sudo ./test.sh
```

I just get back that **command not found**. I can turn the file into an executable via the command the command line:

```
chmod +x test.sh
```

and the code correctly outputs

```
hello
```

I've tried the commands

```
which bash
```

which returned the directory **/bin/bash** and I've also exported this path in my **.bashrc** to no avail. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated thanks! I'm running Linux mint just for clarity.

Comment: Are you entering "./test.sh" on the command line, or something else? What message do you get?

Comment: oh sorry i completely forgot to write that. I'm entering ./test.sh into the command line and it says permission denied. When i type sudo ./test.sh it just says command not found.

Comment: Whats the output of `stat test.sh`

Comment: Check that chmod +x is actually working: ls -l the file and verify that it has execute permission set.

Comment: Does it work if you remove the "#!/bin/bash" from the script file?

Comment: stat test.sh outputs 
[
File: 'test.sh'
  Size: 33         Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 802h/2050d Inode: 2239860     Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/ anthony)   Gid: ( 1000/ anthony)
Access: 2018-06-05 23:44:51.276196037 +0930
Modify: 2018-06-05 23:44:51.276196037 +0930
Change: 2018-06-05 23:44:51.276196037 +0930
 Birth: -
]

Comment: 0644 means that execute permissions aren't set.

Comment: chmod +x test.sh definitely works. Changes it into an executable that runs with ./test.sh like i want.

Comment: Then what remains to fix?

Comment: i want it to run after just ./test.sh without using the command chmod +x. Isn't that hows shebangs work?

Comment: No. You need to have permission to execute to execute.

Comment: The shebang just tells the executor what shell or other program (perl, etc.) to use to read the commands.

Comment: ok, how do i do that?

Comment: You did it. #!/bin/bash says to use bash. chmod +x says to let you execute the file as a command.

Answer (score 0):

```
chmod +x test.sh
```

Setting the executable bit is exactly what's needed. A script needs both a shebang line *and* executable permission to be run. Otherwise you have to invoke a shell explicitly with, say, `bash test.sh`. The executable bit lets you write `./test.sh`.

Comment: the script works without the shebang though if i do the chmod + test.sh. So whats the purpose of the shebang then?

Comment: It's redundant if the shebang is #!/bin/bash and your interpreter is bash. But if the shebang is "#!/usr/bin/env python" and the script is written in python, or maybe if the script gets run in a shell other than bash (rare I suppose) it makes a lot of difference.